# How can I determine the cointegration rank of $\ y_t $ of a bivariate stochastic process?

Tags: self-study, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

What steps do I need to undertake to determine the cointergration rank of $\ y_t $ ?

I am looking at a VAR(2) model that is a bivariate stochastic process.

[image]

---

Ok, I tried to calculate - (I - A_1 - A_2); the rank I get is 1

Comment: Have you tried a time series textbook? Or some lecture notes? Your will find answers in many texts. Finally, there are threads on Cross Validated that address similar question, have you tried looking them up?

Comment: Sitting over Hamilition, but I dont get how to do it properly. I know the relationship of interest is 0<r<K

Comment: But I do not get the whole concept of moving fom VAR to VECM etc.

Comment: OK, Hamilton is a good reference but not a good introductory text, IMHO. Have you read about the Engle-Granger procedure or the Johansen procedure? Both yield the cointegration rank of a bivariate system.

Comment: Since I have a VAR(2) I am not sure if the smartest would be to but it in VAR(1) form first

Comment: No, first you find an adequate VAR, then you test for cointegration and at the same time determine the cointegration rank. Only once you know the rank and have the cointegrating vectors do you construct a VECM. Without the cointegrating vectors you cannot do that. So to answer your original question, first you find an adequate VAR model and then put it in the Johansen machine to get the rank. Or if you do it the Engle-Granger way, one equation will be enough (no VAR model needed).

Comment: Ok, so I will focus on the Johansen procedure and see how far I come. I heard of it but never applied it. Can I post solutions here?

Comment: Which books do you recommend? I also have Lütkepohl but both books dont help a lot when it comes to exection

Comment: I suppose it is fine to post a solution. I like Lütkepohl. An easier book is Zivot "Modelling Financial Time Series with S-PLUS" (2006), I think it is just great. Looking forward to his new volume (promised since May 2014, still not there).

Comment: Zivot, I also cannot handle. Seems to be too advanced. The first thing I would do is to substract the lagged vectors, here y_t-2. or?

Comment: Does anyone know good examples?

Comment: I need the rank of the error-correction coefficient matrix but I do not know how to find it.

Comment: Cannot handle it...

Comment: Johansen procedure is not easy. Engle-Granger is pretty trivial, though. Since you have a bivariate system, the only possible ranks are 0, 1, 2. Rank 0 results when the series are integrated, but no linear combination is stationary. Rank 1 results when the series are integrated but there exists a unique stationary combination. Rank 2 results when all linear combinations are stationary, and so the series are not integrated to begin with. Focusing on ranks 0 vs. rank 1, you test the presence of unit root in the residuals from an OLS regression of $y_t$ on $x_t$. Present --> 0, absent --> 1.

Comment: Thank you. But I am still confused. I would look if the VAR(2) model is stable: if thereare roots on the unit circle then some or all of the variables  may also be cointegrated. Then write down the VECM and look at the cointegration relations. Sorry my skills are to mediocre to solve it. Can someone show me each single step on the the above example? The Var(2) confuses but although it should not make a big difference..;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53071/discussion-between-bonsaibubble-and-richard-hardy).

Comment: Where can I post my answers?

Comment: Apparently, the reviewer requires you to post the answer as an edit to the OP. Which means, you can include it at the end of the OP. I am sorry your answer was downvoted. I am giving you +1 on the question to compensate for that.